# Get_object_vars($worker) doesn't work, while $object->value works

Tags: php, object, pdo, oop

EDIT: Thats more invoking code:

```
$worker = new Worker(); // :|
$worker->addWorker($_POST);
echo 'Post vars:<br>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo 'Object Worker parameters:<br>';
echo $worker->name;
get_object_vars(serialize($worker));
echo 'create<br>';
var_dump(serialize($worker));
$_SESSION['save_confirm'] = serialize($worker);
```

It looks like that:
var_dump shows correctly:

> array(8) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Name" ["surname"]=> string(7) "Surname" ["dob"]=> string(10) "dd/mm/yyyy" ["skills"]=> string(3) "ERN" ["postcode"]=> string(8) "Postcode" ["street"]=> string(6) "Street" ["email"]=> string(5) "Email" ["action"]=> string(6) "create" }

while get_object_vars doesn't work, echo $worker->name gives propper value.
 , there's PDO statement in this object, but ther's also:

`public function __sleep () { unset($conn); }`

EDIT:
Classes:

```
class Worker extends Core {
    public $name;
    public $surname;
    public $dob;
    public $skills;
    public $postcode;
    public $street;
    public $email;
    public $tel;
    public $erefnumber;

    // Adding worker to object
    public function addWorker(  array $postArray)
    {
          $this->name = $postArray['name'];
          $this->surname = $postArray['surname'];
          $this->dob = $postArray['dob'];
          $this->skills = $postArray['skills'];
          $this->postcode = $postArray['postcode'];
          $this->street = $postArray['street'];
          $this->email = $postArray['email'];
          $this->tel = $postArray['tel'];
          $this->erefnumber = $postArray['erefnumber'];
    }

    //Saving worker data to database, need provide group name (table name)
    public function saveWorker($group) {
        if(isset($this->conn)) {
            try
            {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //catch exceptions
                $q = query('INSERT INTO :group(name, surname, dob, skills, postcode, street, email, tel, erefnumber) VALUES(
                :name,
                :surname,
                :dob,
                :skills,
                :postcode,
                :street,
                :email,
                :tel,
                :erefnumber)'); //sql query with group name
                $query = $pdo->prepare($q);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':group', $group, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':surname', $surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':dob', $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':skills', $skills, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':postcode', $postcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':street', $street, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':tel', $tel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt -> bindValue(':erefnumber', $erefnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $results = $query->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) 
            {
              return 'There was some error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        else {
        echo 'no connection  (saveWorkers)';
        }

        unset($stmt);
        return var_dump($list);
        //no exceptions

    }

class Core {
    public $conn;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbConnect();
    }
    public function dbConnect() {

        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = '3307';
        $username = 'modium_test';
        $password = 'test';
        $database ='modium_test';   
        try{
                $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database.';port='.$port, $username, $password );
                echo 'Connection successful!';
                echo var_dump($this->conn);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }   
    }

    public function __sleep () {
        unset($conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the object has a bunch of magic methods. What's the code for it?

Comment: Just to be sure: are you assigning return of `get_object_vars` to anything? it does not print any output, just return an array of object variables and values;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing object to `get_object_vars`, but a string.

```
get_object_vars(serialize($worker));
```

should be

```
$object_vars = get_object_vars($worker);
```

and now `var_dump($object_vars);` will show what you want.

Comment: So if I can var_dump(object), what's the difference between it and var_dump(get_object_vars($worker));

Im doing it all cause I want to send object as a cookie, or object parameters as a cookie and recreate one. And serialize doest work for me.

Comment: `get_object_vars` returns an array, so output will be similar to your `var_dump($_POST);` Array is also better idea to store data in session than storing an object.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the class properties of the $worker object are protected or private visability. Do a

```
var_dump($worker);
```

If is is the case, get_object_vars() won't be able to see them as the are inaccessible from outside the class.

Comment: As you can see they'r not. But, var_dump($worker) works... I don't understand.